# Scoped Service needs to be injected into all services

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, scoped

I have a controller with a scoped service.  IMyService

I also have a service ISecondaryService which requires this scoped service.

My controller sets a property MyProperty `IMyService` in the constructor

When I look `ISecondaryService's` constructor I need to have the same injected service.

However, `MyProperty` is null within `ISecondaryService`

What could cause this?

Im using .NET Core 3.1

```
public interface IMyService
{
   string MyProperty {get;set;}
}

public class MyService: IMyService
{
   public string MyProperty {get;set;}
}

public MyController
{
    public MyController(ISecondaryService secondaryService, 
                              IMyService myService): base( myService)
    {
       _myService = myService;
       myService.MyProperty = "Hello";  
    }
}

public SecondaryService: ISecondaryService
{
    public SecondaryService(IMyService myService)
    {
        _myService = myService;
    }
}
```

I need _myService.MyProperty to be Hello

In startup I have

```
services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();
services.AddTransient<ISecondaryService, SecondaryService>();
```

Paul

Comment: How are you injecting secondary service?

Comment: Please show the code where you register both services, as well as the code where you inject them. It's hard to know what you're doing without seeing code. Also, please clarify what technology you are using (eg .NET Core, ASP.NET, MVC, Blazor, WPF, etc) as that might be important

Comment: Did you check if property is set after controller constructor finishes? Because it cannot be set yet in constructor of SecondaryService (because SecondarySerivce constructor runs before controller one)

Comment: ok thats my problem then.  Its the controller that setting MyProperty.  I thought this was the same object so any change I make is global?

Answer (score 0):

program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMyService>(new MyService());
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISecondaryService>(sp =>
{
    var myService = sp.GetService<IMyService>();
    return new ISecondaryService(myService);
});
```

You need to register the 1st service then register the second one and injecting the first one in it.
From there, if your controller expect ISecondaryService to be injected, it will also provide IMyService.

Comment: What if I have a far more complex class with a lot of dependencies?  I would have to do this for all of the parameters?  Seconary Service is transient

Comment: If you need to inject a service depending on another injected service, this is how you should do. If it's too complex, then maybe your architecture is to be refactored...